# Here Routing API with no instructions

Tags: here-api

im looking to reduce the size of the responses when calculate route, currently im using maneuverAttributes=sh so the response is long, but there are fields im not using at all, like instruction text and street names, i didn´t find how to avoid those in the response. It is possible?

Also, there is any "definition" setup i can make for the route shape? my intention is to receive a approximate of the route shape, using only the legs is way to generic, but the points for the route shape are way too detailed for my use case, and i want to reduce the response size and memory use in the app.

Comment: Can you post also the API request?

Comment: the request is 
`https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={0}&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&instructionformat=text&maneuverAttributes=sh&waypoint0=geo!{1}&waypoint1=geo!{2}`